# Prove that there is a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) \int_0^1 g(x)dx =g(c) \int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I = [0,1]$ and $f,g : I \to \Bbb{R}$ be real-valued functions such that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $I$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Prove that there is a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
f(c) \int_0^1 g(x)dx =g(c)  \int_0^1 f(x)dx.
$$
Is it true if $f$ and $g$ are complex valued function?

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $I$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, there exists $ c \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
g'(c)[f(1)-f(0)]=f'(c)[g(1)-g(0)]
$$

I tried to consider a function $y(x)  = (\int_0^1 f(x) dx) (\int_0^1 g(x) dx) $ so that I can apply mean value theorem. I am confused to go further step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt, F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$. Then $F,G$ are differentiable functions. By the generalized mean value theorem we have
$$\begin{align*}G'(c)[F(1)-F(0)] &= F'(c)[G(1)-G(0)]\\
g(c)\int_0^1 F'(t)dt &= f(c)\int_0^1 G'(t)dt\\
g(c)\int_0^1 f(t)dt &= f(c)\int_0^1 g(t)dt \end{align*}$$
for some $c\in I$.

Comment: Is this statement true if both f and g are complex-valued functions?

Comment: Do you mean $f, g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ or $f, g: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$? I don't know in either case, but my gut says no for the second case.

Comment: Yes for $f,g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Do you have any example in your mind?

Answer (score 3):

Try $H(t) = \big(\int_0^t f(x)\, dx\big) \big(\int_0^1 g(x)\, dx\big) -\big(\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx\big) \big(\int_0^t g(x)\, dx\big)$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.